# Alias case statement

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, view

I have stored procedure that sometimes return negative number in the ID. (on purpose).
In additional, I have a view that shows this table (simple select), but I don't want that '-' will appear in the ID column, I mean, if the number is negative - I want to add the letter 'A' to the ID without '-'.

How can I do this?

Comment: Which dbms are you using here? (Very few of them support ANSI SQL stored procecures...)

Comment: PL/pgSQL? PL/SQL? T-SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT REPLACE (ID, '-', 'A') MyID
```

Or if you were wanting to append the 'A'

```
SELECT REPLACE (ID, '-', '') + 'A' MyID
```

Comment: There is no need to cast to varchar if the ID is an integer.

Answer (score 1):

If correct I understood, you could use [**REPLACE**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in following: `REPLACE(ID, '-', 'A')`

So in this case will be `A115` instead of `-115`

Also you can make It with [**CASE**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx):

```
CASE WHEN Id < 0 THEN 'A' + CAST(Id * -1 AS NVARCHAR(20)) ELSE CAST(Id AS NVARCHAR(20)) END
```